# How to "extrapolate" values of panel data in R?

Tags: r

I have a panel data with NA values like below:

```
    uid year    month   day value
1   1   2016    8   1   NA
2   1   2016    8   2   NA
3   1   2016    8   3   30
4   1   2016    8   4   NA
5   1   2016    8   5   20
6   2   2016    8   1   40
7   2   2016    8   2   NA
8   2   2016    8   3   50
9   2   2016    8   4   NA
10  2   2016    8   5   NA
```

I would like to perform a linear interpolation, so I wrote this code:

```
library(dplyr)  
library(zoo)

panel_df <- group_by(panel_df, userid)
panel_df <- mutate(panel_df, value=na.approx(value, na.rm=FALSE))
```

then I get the output:

```
    uid year    month   day value
1   1   2016    8   1   NA
2   1   2016    8   2   NA
3   1   2016    8   3   30
4   1   2016    8   4   25
5   1   2016    8   5   20
6   2   2016    8   1   40
7   2   2016    8   2   45
8   2   2016    8   3   50
9   2   2016    8   4   NA
10  2   2016    8   5   NA
```

Here the approx method interpolates NA values successfully but does not extrapolate.

Is there any good way to replace the value of the 1st and 2nd rows with first non-NA value of this user(30)? Similary, how I can replace the value of the 9th and 10th rows with last non-NA value of this user(50)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is by using `na.spline()` from same package `zoo`:

```
panel_df <- group_by(panel_df, uid)
panel_df <- mutate(panel_df, value=na.spline(value))
panel_df
Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
Groups: uid [2]

     uid  year month   day value
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1      1  2016     8     1    40
2      1  2016     8     2    35
3      1  2016     8     3    30
4      1  2016     8     4    25
5      1  2016     8     5    20
6      2  2016     8     1    40
7      2  2016     8     2    45
8      2  2016     8     3    50
9      2  2016     8     4    55
10     2  2016     8     5    60
```